# How to find the words correspond to month and replace it with numerical?

Tags: python, replace

How to find the words that correspond to the month "January, February, March,.. etc."  and replace them with numerical "01, 02, 03,.."

I tried the code below

```
def transformMonths(string):
    rep = [("May", "05"), ("June", "06")]
    for pat, repl in rep:
        s = re.sub(pat, repl, string)
    return s

print( transformMonths('I was born on June 24 and my sister was born on May 17') )
```

My code provides this result `('I was born on 06 24 and my sister was born on May 17')`

However, I want the output to be like this `('I was born on 06 24 and my sister was born on 05 17')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing the replacement on the initial (unmodified) string at each iteration so you end up with only one month name being replaced. You can fix that by assigning `string` instead of `s` in the loop (and return `string` at the end).

Note that your approach does not require a regular expression and could use a simple string replace: `string = string.replace(pat,repl)`.

In both cases, because the replacement does not take into account word boundaries, the function would replace partial words such as:

```
"Mayor Smith was elected on May 25" --> "05or Smith was elected on 05 25".
```

You can fix that in your regular expression by adding `\b` before and after each month name.  This will ensure that the month names are only found if they are between word boundaries.

The `re.sub` can perform multiple replacements with varying values if you give it a function instead of a fixed string.  So you can build a combined regular expression that will find all the months and replace the words that are found using a dictionary:

```
import re
def numericMonths(string):
    months = {"January":"01",  "Ffebruary":"02","March":"03",   "April":"04",
              "May":"05",      "June":"06",    "July":"07",    "August":"08",
              "September":"09","October":"10", "November":"11","December":"12"}
    pattern = r"\b("+"|".join(months)+r")\b" # all months as distinct words
    return re.sub(pattern,lambda m:months[m.group()],string)
```

output:

```
numericMonths('I was born on June 24 and my sister was born on May 17') 

'I was born on 06 24 and my sister was born on 05 17'
```